# PSR-4 Namespace with Sub Directories

Tags: laravel, composer-php, psr-4

Im having trouble with my Laravel application and PSR-4 autoloading. I read that you can have multiple 'sub directory' structure in namespaces like this...

VendorName\ApplicationName\(SubDir)\ClassName

Basically I have my user repositories like so...

```
Acme\Repositories\EloquentUserRepoistory
Acme\Repositories\UserRepositoryInterface
Acme\Repositories\Repository
Acme\Repositories\RepositoryServiceProvider
```

All with the namespace `Acme\Repositories`, but i want to have this directory structure...

```
Acme\Repositories\UserRepository\EloquentUserRepoistory
Acme\Repositories\UserRepository\UserRepositoryInterface
Acme\Repositories\Repository
Acme\Repositories\RepositoryServiceProvider
```

but when I move the user repo and interface to the folder `UserRepository`, i get class not found?

Im sure im just not getting something really simple about namespaces here?

**EDIT**

I guess what im asking is how to have the additional directory `UserRepository` to keep the different repositories separate from say OrderRepositories?

Answer (score 0):

If you moved `UserRepositoryInterface` to `Acme\Repositories\UserRepository\UserRepositoryInterface.php` directory, you need to put `UserRepositoryInterface` in correct namespace:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Repositories\UserRepository;

interface UserRepositoryInterface {

}
```

and then in other files to access you need to also use this new namespace and not the old one

Comment: OK, here's what I done... i made a directory at Acme\Repositories\UserRepositories and placed UserRepositoryInterface inside it, I changed the namespace inside the file to Acme\Repositories\UserRepositories... but PHPStorm throws a fit, saying 'Undefined Constant UserRepositories'... php debug says "Interface 'Acme\Repositories\UserRepositoryInterface' not found" ??

Comment: And why you use `Acme\Repositories` when you moved it into `Acme\Repositories\UserRepositories` and in the question you asked about `Acme\Repositories\UserRepository` ? It's not the same